# Loading data with JSON.parse: Unexpected token /

Tags: json, parsing, xmlhttprequest, token

I'm pretty new with this JSON and AJAX staff, so I was following a tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw&t=1029s.
The thing is that I have followed the steps exactly like in the video, but I get the following error:

```
VM34:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.theRequest.onload (loader.js:5)
```

My JSON script:

```
[
    {
        "name":"一",
        "sound": {
            "kunyomi": ["ひと．つ"],
            "onyomi": ["イチ"]
        },
        "description":"Representaba la unidad, el absoluto. Cuando funciona como componente, este carácter adquiere el significado de suelo o de techo según su posición: si se encuentra encima de otro componente, toma el significado de techo; si está debajo, de suelo. Todas las formas antiguas de los números están asociadas a fuerzas del universo y a la mitología. Los números pares son el ying y los impares son el yang.",
        "examples":["-月[いちがつ] - Enero", "-日[ついたち] - Día uno", "-回[いっかい] - Dos veces", "-階[いっかい] - Primer Piso"]
    },
    {
        "name":"ニ",
        "sound": {
            "kunyomi": ["ふた．つ"],
            "onyomi": ["ニ、ジ"]
        },
        "description":"Representa el cielo 一 y la tierra 一, el ying y el yang. Al igual que en el caso de los numerales romanos, el kanji de dos es una simple duplicación del trazo horizontal que significa uno.",
        "examples":["二月[にがつ] - Febrero", "二日[ふつか] - Día dos", "二回[にかい] - Dos veces"]
    }
]
```

And I call that JSON with the following code:

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1/japones_flat/kanjis_n5.json');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    "use strict";
    var response = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(response[0]);
};
ourRequest.send();
```

I made a little research and it looks like the problem resides in the JSON.parse method, saying that the token "/" is making troubles. After that, I noticed that Dreamweaver had left by default a comment in my .json file, so I deleted it (Because it started with "/") but I keep getting this anoying error. Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try clearing your cache

Comment: I didn't think about that, but it has a lot of sense. It worked perfectly! Thanks!